# "There is no formatter for 'java' files installed" message when trying to format my Java code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, format, formatter

I've tried countless things I've seen online today, but I just can't get the RedHat Java Support extension to format the code. It used to work for me in the past.
At some point today, I completely uninstalled VS Code, along with all the settings in %APPDATA% and %USERPROFILE%.
I reinstalled it and installed the **Extension Pack for Java** (Which installs RedHat as well) and it still doesn't work. I've tried playing around with the settings.json file all day long but nothing seems to make it work.
These are my current settings there:

```
{
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"editor.suggestSelection": "first",
"vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
"java.format.enabled": true,
"[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
},
"java.format.settings.url": "file:///[PathTo..]\\eclipse-formatter.xml",
"editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `file:///` as the value of `"java.format.settings.url"`. Delete this setting and readd it, see if it helps.

If not, delete formatter.xml in current opened project then click **Java: Open Java Formatter Settings with Preview** from Command Palette, create a default one, it will generate `java-formatter.xml` in the folder `.vscode` and `settings.json` will have

```
"java.format.settings.url": ".vscode/java-formatter.xml"
```

Then turn to .java files and **Format Document**. So if this default one works but your `eclipse-formatter.xml` not, please check if there's something wrong with it. Or you may choose `java-formatter.xml` since it's kind of eclipse formatting.